# Difference in days between two dates in GraphDB

Tags: sparql, graphdb

I need some help to calculate the difference between two dates with SPARQL in Ontotext GraphDB. I know that SPARQL protocol does not support arithmetic operation on dates, however some SPARQL engines support it.

Just as an example in Fuseki I could do .

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?duration
WHERE {
  BIND (("2011-02-04T14:45:13.815-05:00"^^xsd:dateTime - "2011-02- 
  02T14:45:13.815-05:00"^^xsd:dateTime) AS ?duration)
}
```

the result is duration: `"P2DT0H0M0.000S"^^xsd:duration`. Then I can get 2 days diff, or Virtuoso provides a built-in function `bif:datediff`.

My question is, if is there something similar on GraphDB to solve this easy problem without a big workaround.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [On FactForge](http://factforge.net/sparql?name=&infer=false&sameAs=false&query=PREFIX%20dbo:%20%3Chttp:%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20dbr:%20%3Chttp:%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20xsd:%20%3Chttp:%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0Aselect%20*%20%7B%20%0Aservice%20%3Chttps:%2F%2Fquery.wikidata.org%2Fsparql%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20BIND%20((%222011-02-04T14:45:13%22%5E%5Exsd:dateTime%20-%20%222011-02-02T14:45:14%22%5E%5Exsd:dateTime)%20AS%20%3Fduration)%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Comment: For datetimes within the same month, you could [extract](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-date-time) days, hours, minutes etc. and perform calculations manually.

Comment: Hi Stanislav Kralin, thanks for your help. I will mark your first response as a solution. However, I still have the same problem, because is a close network, no internet access from the VM where the server is running. No way I may use external service. And unfortunately the dates are not within the same month. So, for now, I will request the data with sparql and finish the calculation and response on a backend function. Thanks.

Comment: So what about accepting the answer :)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was solved in [8.7.0](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/8.7/standard/release-notes.html#graphdb-8-7-0) (released 28 September):

> GDB-2887 As a GraphDB user I need support of “+” / “-” operations between xsd:dateTime and xsd:duration with SPARQL

Now your query should return `"P2DT0H0M0.000S"^^xsd:dateTimeDuration`.

---

Alternatively, one could use federated queries to public endpoints based on Virtuoso, Blazegraph, Fuseki etc.:

```sql
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX bif: <bif:>
SELECT ?duration1 ?duration2 ?duration3 ?duration4 { 
    VALUES (?start ?end)
        {("2011-02-02T14:45:14"^^xsd:dateTime "2011-02-04T14:45:13"^^xsd:dateTime)}
    SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql>           #-- Virtuoso
        { BIND ((?end - ?start)/86400.0 AS ?duration1) }
    SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql>           #-- Virtuoso
        { BIND (bif:datediff("day", ?start, ?end) AS ?duration2) }
    SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql>   #-- Blazegraph
        { BIND ((?end - ?start) AS ?duration3) }
    SERVICE <http://zbw.eu/beta/sparql/stw/query> #-- Fuseki
        { BIND (day(?end - ?start) AS ?duration4) }
}
```

[Try on FactForge!](http://factforge.net/sparql?name=&infer=false&sameAs=false&query=PREFIX+xsd%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0APREFIX+bif%3A+%3Cbif%3A%3E%0ASELECT+%3Fduration1+%3Fduration2+%3Fduration3+%3Fduration4+%7B+%0A++++VALUES+(%3Fstart+%3Fend)%0A++++++++%7B(%222011-02-02T14%3A45%3A14%22%5E%5Exsd%3AdateTime+%222011-02-04T14%3A45%3A13%22%5E%5Exsd%3AdateTime)%7D%0A++++SERVICE+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fsparql%3E+++++++++++%23--+Virtuoso%0A++++++++%7B+BIND+((%3Fend+-+%3Fstart)%2F86400.0+AS+%3Fduration1)+%7D%0A++++SERVICE+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fsparql%3E+++++++++++%23--+Virtuoso%0A++++++++%7B+BIND+(bif%3Adatediff(%22day%22%2C+%3Fstart%2C+%3Fend)+AS+%3Fduration2)+%7D%0A++++SERVICE+%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fquery.wikidata.org%2Fsparql%3E+++%23--+Blazegraph%0A++++++++%7B+BIND+((%3Fend+-+%3Fstart)+AS+%3Fduration3)+%7D%0A++++SERVICE+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fzbw.eu%2Fbeta%2Fsparql%2Fstw%2Fquery%3E+%23--+Fuseki%0A++++++++%7B+BIND+(day(%3Fend+-+%3Fstart)+AS+%3Fduration4)+%7D%0A%7D)